# Have a working Excel macro, need help tweaking it

Tags: vba, excel

I have this macro that does a good job of copying rows to another sheet.  There are a few tweaks I'd like to make to it, but I'm not sure how.

1) I'd like to have it copy to a new worksheet.

2) Is there a way to simplify the "If Range("G" & r).Value = "46704" Or" section? Like list them with commas or something?

```
Sub Allen()
Dim lr As Long, lr2 As Long, r As Long, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, n As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
n = 2
lr = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
lr2 = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For r = 2 To lr
    If Range("G" & r).Value = "46704" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46741" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46743" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46745" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46748" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46765" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46773" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46774" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46788" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46797" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46798" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46799" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46801" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46802" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46803" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46804" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46805" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46806" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46807" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46808" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46809" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46814" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46815" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46816" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46818" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46819" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46825" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46835" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46845" _
        Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46850" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46851" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46852" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46853" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46854" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46855" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46856" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46857" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46858" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46859" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46860" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46861" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46862" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46863" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46864" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46865" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46866" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46867" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46868" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46869" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46885" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46895" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46896" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46897" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46898" Or Range("G" & r).Value = "46899" Then
            Rows(r).Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("A" & n + 1)
            n = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        End If
    Next r
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `I'd like to have it copy to a new worksheet` It looks like you're already copying to a new worksheet. Or do you mean a new Excel document?

Comment: What sheet do you expect the `If Range("G" & r)...` lines? You don't reference a worksheet there like you do later `ws.Cells()`...  Also, is the `46704`... all a range? Perhaps just `If [range] >= 46704 and [range] <= 46899`?

Comment: No, unfortunately, these are a specific set of unique values.

Comment: The `If` statement could potentially be done as `If InStr("|46704|46741|46743|....|46898|46899|", "|" & ws1.Range("G" & r).Value & "|") > 0 Then`.  (I'm assuming the values you are checking are from `"Sheet1"` based on the use of `For r = 2 To lr` where `lr` is the number of rows in column G on `"Sheet1"`.)

Comment: A lot of the suggestions that have been made are over my head, but I'm working on learning and implementing them as I go.  Thank you for all your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified versions using an **`AutoFilter()`**

---

> ```
> Public Sub AllenAutoFilter()
>    Const SET1 = "46704,46741,46743,46745,46748,46765,46773,46774,46788,46797,46798,46799,"
>    Const SET2 = "46801,46802,46803,46804,46805,46806,46807,46808,46809,46814,46815,46816,"
>    Const SET3 = "46818,46819,46825,46835,46845,46850,46851,46852,46853,46854,46855,46856,"
>    Const SET4 = "46857,46858,46859,46860,46861,46862,46863,46864,46865,46866,46867,46868,"
>    Const SET5 = "46869,46885,46895,46896,46897,46898,46899"
>    Const ALL = SET1 & SET2 & SET3 & SET4 & SET5
>
>    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long, arr As Variant
>
>     arr = Split(ALL, ",")
>     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
>     With ThisWorkbook
>         Set ws1 = .Worksheets("Sheet1")
>         Set ws2 = Workbooks.Add.Worksheets(1)    'New Workbook, Sheet1
>     End With
>
>     ws1.AutoFilterMode = False
>     lr1 = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
>     lr2 = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
>
>     With ws1.UsedRange
>         .Columns(7).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=arr, Operator:=xlFilterValues
>         .Offset(1).Resize(lr1 - 1).Rows.Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("A" & lr2)
>     End With
>     ws1.AutoFilterMode = False
>
>     ws1.Activate
>     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
> End Sub
> ```

Comment: I am working on implementing the section version.  It works awesome. Thanks!  The thing I'd like to be able to do is have it copy to a new workbook. Is that possible? 
p.s. I see I said worksheet in the original post, I meant workbook.

Comment: I updated `AllenAutoFilter()` to copy data to a new Workbook. Every time you run it you'll get a new file (behind the initial one) usually called Book2, 3, etc

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to copy to a new sheet:

```
Set ws2 = Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
```

Also, you need to reference a worksheet here Range("G" & r).Value

```
ws1.Range("G" & r).Value
```

Hope this help.

Comment: `Rows(r)` should also be `ws1.Rows(r)`, and `lr = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row` should be `lr = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row`, and `ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` should be `ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use case statement

```
Option Explicit

Sub Allen()
    Dim lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long, r As Long, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, n As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    n = 2
    lr1 = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
    lr2 = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For r = 2 To lr1
            Select Case CDec(Range("G" & r).Value) - 46000      ' convert to number and subtract 46000 to make lookup list smaller

                Case 704, 741, 743, 745, 748, 765, 773, 774, _
                     788, 797, 798, 799, 801, 802, 803, 804, _
                     805, 806, 807, 808, 809, 814, 815, 816, _
                     818, 819, 825, 835, 845, 850, 851, 852, _
                     853, 854, 855, 856, 857, 858, 859, 860, _
                     861, 862, 863, 864, 865, 866, 867, 868, _
                     869, 885, 895, 896, 897, 898, 899

                    Rows(r).Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("A" & n + 1)
                    n = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            End Select
        Next r
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I implemented the case section, and have it working.  Thank you so much for your input.

Answer (score 0):

here is one that uses range objects only (no counting lines)

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

    Dim lr1 As Range
    Set lr1 = Range(ws1.Cells(2, "G"), ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp))

    Dim lr2 As Range
    Set lr2 = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1) ' point to next empty cell

    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In lr1

        Select Case CDec(r.Value) - 46000   ' convert to number and subtract 46000 to make lookup list smaller

            Case 704, 741, 743, 745, 748, 765, 773, 774, _
                 788, 797, 798, 799, 801, 802, 803, 804, _
                 805, 806, 807, 808, 809, 814, 815, 816, _
                 818, 819, 825, 835, 845, 850, 851, 852, _
                 853, 854, 855, 856, 857, 858, 859, 860, _
                 861, 862, 863, 864, 865, 866, 867, 868, _
                 869, 885, 895, 896, 897, 898, 899

                r.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=lr2
                Set lr2 = lr2.Offset(1)              ' point to next empty cell
        End Select

    Next r

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```